# No thumbnails for files on the network in Windows 8 explorer

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, nas, thumbnails

I have a fresh Windows 8 machine which I just unwrapped, but after moving all of my files to a NAS box I have lost all thumbnails in explorer. I browse to the folder and all my JPEGs just have a standard icon. How can I get explorer to show the thumbnails?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Have you tried rebooting (to refresh icon caches, etc)?  Is `thumbs.db` being written to the NAS? How did you copy them to the NAS?

Answer (score 3):

After much research I have found the one solution that seems to make a difference on my Windows 8 system, and that is:

Create the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer:

(DWORD 32) :  DisableThumbnailsOnNetworkFolders  :  Value = 0

Once this was set and the system rebooted, explorer is now merrily making thumbnails for folders resident on network drives.

Comment: +1 - The above worked for me on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, however I had to enable the 'Desktop Experience' feature as well. A logon/logoff was enough for the change to take effect but I suspect this may vary from case to case.